# What is proxy server in Oracle Service Bus? What scenario can we can use it?

Tags: osb

I am calling a https rest service from my business service which is outside my network.

Can I use proxy server for this? Or is there any other way so can I can configure forward proxy in osb.

Through terminal i can connect the rest service by
wget https://h-api.online-metrix.net/api/session-query?WSDL -e use_proxy=yes -e https_proxy=fwdproxy:3128

In my business service I have given https://h-api.online-metrix.net/api/session-query end point.

Now how can I configure the forward proxy?

Comment: Do you want to use the proxy server for all traffic, or just this business service?

Comment: Just the business service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 12c you have the REST adapter that you can configure in Jdeveloper. If using 11g, you need to play with the HTTP headers and create a proxy service
One example is here

http://www.soawork.com/2014/01/call-restful-service-from-osb.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the OSB *Configuration* in Eclipse (where you put your OSB projects).
2. Create a new Proxy *Server*. (it will end in `.ps`)
3. Configure it with username/password/list of hostnames/ports.

Then

1. Edit the biz ref in your IDE.
2. Switch to the HTTP Transport tab of the service
3. Click Advanced
4. select the Proxy *Server* you configured earlier.
5. export everything to your OSB installation of choice.

Comment: What is the use of proxy server? Can I use it to call rest service which is outside my network?

Comment: Yes that's the main use case: calling services that you cannot reach without a http proxy set.